# Plotly and ggplot2 hover text in barplot from R not working

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

This is my first question here if I've made any mistake on posting it or explaining my issue I will be happy to hear any feedback.

I'm building a tool in R using Shiny, ggplot and Plotly. I've got an example from plotly [library](https://plot.ly/ggplot2/geom_bar/) where I can see that's possible to have a tooltip when using ggplot to render a graph.

Follows my example code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("distPlot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlotly({
  dat <- data.frame(
  time = factor(c("Lunch","Dinner"), levels=c("Lunch","Dinner")),
  total_bill = c(14.89, 17.23)
)

p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=time, y=total_bill, fill=time)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
    p <- p + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
    
    ggplotly(p)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I use the above code the tooltip does not show up but if I remove the fill = X2 parameter the tooltip appears:

```
     p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=time, y=total_bill)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

In my application I need to have the fill parameter to separate the "groups" that I have by color and show the legend.

I have searched for many "workarounds" on the internet using javascript and other solutions, but since it's a native feature from plotly I would like to have this working in a simpler way.

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: Try `g <- plotly_build(p)`. Then look at the structure of g, you should find `g$x$data[[i]]$text`. Look at what the value is there and changing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of a known issue, you can use this to fix it:

```
p <- ggplotly(p)

for (i in 1:length(p$x$data)){
    p$x$data[[i]]$text <- c(p$x$data[[i]]$text, "") 
}
p
```

Comment: Hello @GGamba thanks for your answer, the first option works fine, however, the second doesn't. I believe this is a bug and I couldn't find a workaround.